# DataOutputStream only sends on close

Tags: java

When I run this code without the close method the server cannot receive the message!

client:

```
        Socket con = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 12345);

        InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();

        byte[] key = new byte[]{5};

        DataOutputStream dos = EncryptIO.getEncryptedOutputStream(key, os);
        DataInputStream dis = EncryptIO.getEncryptedInputStream(key, is);

        dos.writeUTF("Player 2");
        dos.close(); //with this the server receives the message
        String opUsername = dis.readUTF();
```

server:

```
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(12345);
        Socket con = serverSocket.accept();

        InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();

        byte[] key = new byte[]{5};

        DataOutputStream dos = EncryptIO.getEncryptedOutputStream(key, os);
        DataInputStream dis = EncryptIO.getEncryptedInputStream(key, is);

        String opUsername = dis.readUTF();
        System.out.println(opUsername);

        dos.writeUTF("Player 1"); //this line isn't reached because DataInputStream waits for the data
```

Under the DataOutput/InputStream are Cipherstreams underlying **without** them it works!

EncryptIO code:

```
public static DataInputStream getEncryptedInputStream(byte[] key, InputStream is) throws InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, NoSuchPaddingException {
    try {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, EncryptIO.getAESKey(key), EncryptIO.getIV(key));
        CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(is, cipher);
        return new DataInputStream(cis);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(EncryptIO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return null;
}

public static DataOutputStream getEncryptedOutputStream(byte[] key, OutputStream os) throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
    try {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, EncryptIO.getAESKey(key), EncryptIO.getIV(key));
        CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(os, cipher);
        return new DataOutputStream(cos);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(EncryptIO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

How can I get it DataOutputStream to send the data with the encryption and without closing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I tried flushing os directly if you mean that

Comment: Sorry my comment was incomplete, didn't mean to post it. yes, what I was going to say is that even though DataOutputStream does not have a buffer, the parent stream `os` might, and does in the case of CipherOutputStream, so it will need to be flushed. I would try flushing dos, which should flush all the parent streams.

Comment: What do you mean by *How can I get it to work with the encryption?* What doesn't work?

Comment: I don't mean os directly, but dos

Comment: @AndrewHenle As I said: sending the data

Comment: "the server cannot receive the message!" @AndrewHenle

Comment: You will also need to flush `dis` as well

Comment: @Novaterata An InputStream doesn't have that feature

Comment: OK, so what is "the server"? If the problem is with this "server", what does the comment `//no output not even "OpUsername"` mean?

Comment: @AndrewHenle It means that this line isn't reached and there is no output seen in the console

Comment: So you've not provided the entire context of your problem?  Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem.

Comment: @AndrewHenle please see the edits

Comment: @AaronStein ha never noticed that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From

```
Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")
```

you're using an AES cipher in CBC mode with PKCS5Padding.  Per the [**Java Cryptography Architecture Standard Algorithm Name Documentation for JDK 8**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html) (reformatted, with links per the original):

> **AES**
>
> Advanced Encryption Standard as specified by NIST in [FIPS 197](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/PubsFIPS.html).
>   Also known as the Rijndael algorithm by Joan Daemen and Vincent
>   Rijmen, AES is a 128-bit block cipher supporting keys of 128, 192, and
>   256 bits.
>
> To use the AES cipher with only one valid key size, use the format
>   AES_, where  can be 128, 192, or 256.

and

> **CBC**
>
> Cipher Block Chaining Mode, as defined in [FIPS PUB 81](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips81/fips81.htm).

and

> **PKCS5Padding**
>
> The padding scheme described in [RSA Laboratories, "PKCS #5:
>   Password-Based Encryption Standard," version 1.5, November 1993](http://www.emc.com/emc-plus/rsa-labs/standards-initiatives/pkcs-5-password-based-cryptography-standard.htm).

So, a block cipher, likely at 128 bits (16 bytes), with padding.

Note this from **Cipher Algorithm Modes**:

> **CFB, CFBx**
>
> Cipher Feedback Mode, as defined in [FIPS PUB 81](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips81/fips81.htm).
>
> Using modes such as CFB and OFB, block ciphers can encrypt data in
>   units smaller than the cipher's actual block size. When requesting
>   such a mode, you may optionally specify the number of bits to be
>   processed at a time by appending this number to the mode name as shown
>   in the "DES/CFB8/NoPadding" and "DES/OFB32/PKCS5Padding"
>   transformations. If no such number is specified, a provider-specific
>   default is used. (For example, the SunJCE provider uses a default of
>   64 bits for DES.) **Thus, block ciphers can be turned into byte-oriented
>   stream ciphers by using an 8-bit mode such as CFB8 or OFB8**.

So `"AES/CFB8/NoPadding"` or similar should work as a non-blocked stream cipher.  You may still have to `flush()` the stream, however.  And there will likely be a performance impact.

Comment: Thanks, I would have never thought that it's a problem with the cipher. Thanks for the structured answer